# Select one multiple answers from array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm kinda new to JS and I'm having trouble with selecting multiple inputs from arrays. I have 2 arrays : 1 with questions, another one with answers
Thing is, in the answers one, i want to set a question with multiple answers possible like this

```js
let questions = [
    'How many players do play on a football field?',
    'How much is 6 x 12',
    'How many atoms are present in water?',
    'Who is Daffy Duck?'
];

let responses = [
    22,
    72,
    3,
    ['duck', 'a duck'],
];
```

And I have no idea how to make my code select both answers as true for the last question.

Here is my current code that works but only for the first input. I've been told to use Array.inArray in 2 'for' loops but noob me cannot figure out how to set this up.

```js
function askQuestion(IndexNumber) {
    let answer = (prompt(questions[IndexNumber]));
    let isCorrect = false;

    if (answer == (responses[IndexNumber])) {
        console.log("Correct !");
        isCorrect = true;
    } else {
        console.log("False !");
    }
    addResponseToDom(IndexNumber, isCorrect);
}

let rightAnswers = 0;
let wrongAnswers = 0;

function addResponseToDom(IndexNumber, isCorrect) {

    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let textnode = document.createTextNode(questions[IndexNumber]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    if (isCorrect) {
        rightAnswers++;
        document.querySelector('#right .responses').appendChild(node);
    } else {
        wrongAnswers++;
        document.querySelector('#wrong .responses').appendChild(node);
    }
}


function playQuiz() {
    for (let IndexNumber = 0; IndexNumber < questions.length; IndexNumber++) {
        askQuestion(IndexNumber);
    }
    document.querySelector('#right h2').textContent += '(' + rightAnswers + ')';
    document.querySelector('#wrong h2').textContent += '(' + wrongAnswers + ')';
}

playQuiz();
```

Many thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check the type of `responses[IndexNumber]` by using built-in functions like [`Array.isArray(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and [`Array.includes(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

As an example:

```
...
if (Array.isArray(responses[IndexNumber])) {
    if (responses[IndexNumber].includes(answer)) {
        console.log("Correct !");
        isCorrect = true;
    } else {
        console.log("False !");
    }
} else if (answer == (responses[IndexNumber])) {
    console.log("Correct !");
    isCorrect = true;
} else {
   console.log("False !");
}
...
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the quick turnaround. Was focused on my "for" loop while  I did not realise it was in my starting function, thus no need to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.some` to check against multiple correct answers in the case that the answer is an array.  The snippet shows the right response (Correct to 'a duck' and 'duck') in the console, but your HTML is missing so produces a DOM error.

```
isCorrect = Array.isArray(responses[IndexNumber])?responses[IndexNumber].some(res=>res==answer):responses[IndexNumber]==answer;
```

```js
let questions = [
    'How many players do play on a football field?',
    'How much is 6 x 12',
    'How many atoms are present in water?',
    'Who is Daffy Duck?'
];

let responses = [
    22,
    72,
    3,
    ['duck', 'a duck'],
];


function askQuestion(IndexNumber) {
console.log('here')
    let answer = (prompt(questions[IndexNumber]));
    let isCorrect = false;
    isCorrect = Array.isArray(responses[IndexNumber])?responses[IndexNumber].some(res=>res==answer):responses[IndexNumber]==answer;
    if (isCorrect) {
        console.log("Correct !");
        isCorrect = true;
    } else {
        console.log("False !");
    }
    addResponseToDom(IndexNumber, isCorrect);
}

let rightAnswers = 0;
let wrongAnswers = 0;

function addResponseToDom(IndexNumber, isCorrect) {

    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let textnode = document.createTextNode(questions[IndexNumber]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    if (isCorrect) {
        rightAnswers++;
        document.querySelector('#right .responses').appendChild(node);
    } else {
        wrongAnswers++;
        document.querySelector('#wrong .responses').appendChild(node);
    }
}


function playQuiz() {
    for (let IndexNumber =questions.length-1; IndexNumber >= 0; IndexNumber--) {
        askQuestion(IndexNumber);
    }
    document.querySelector('#right h2').textContent += '(' + rightAnswers + ')';
    document.querySelector('#wrong h2').textContent += '(' + wrongAnswers + ')';
}

playQuiz();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, still not very familiar with ```.some(res=>res==answer) ``` but it will come with time I guess. Thanks !